# c++ cast int to double not working

Tags: c++

```
int main(){
    srand(time(0));
    int numOfTimes;
    int randNum;
    int oneRoll = 0, twoRoll = 0, threeRoll = 0, fourRoll = 0, fiveRoll = 0, sixRoll = 0;
    int onePercent, twoPercent, threePercent, fourPercent, fivePercent, sixPercent;

    int count = 0;
    cout << "How many times would you like to roll the dice?\n";
    cin >> numOfTimes;

    while (numOfTimes <= 0){
        cout << "Invalid entry enter a number greater than 0\n";
        cout << "How many times would you like to roll the dice?\n";
        cin >> numOfTimes;
    }

    while (count < numOfTimes)
        {
            randNum = rand() % 6 + 1;

            switch (randNum)
                {
                case 1:
                    oneRoll++;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    twoRoll++;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    threeRoll++;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    fourRoll++;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    fiveRoll++;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    sixRoll++;
                    break;
                default:
                    cout << "\n";
                }

            count++;
        }

    onePercent = (int)((oneRoll*100.0) /numOfTimes);
    twoPercent = (int)((twoRoll*100.0) / numOfTimes);

    cout << " # Rolled          # Times % Times" << endl;
    cout << "---------  --------    --------" << endl;
    cout << "1      " << oneRoll << "       " <<double (onePercent)  << endl;
    cout << "2      " << twoRoll << "       " << "" << endl;
    cout << "3      " << threeRoll << "     " << ""<< endl;
    cout << "4      " << fourRoll << "      " <<""  << endl;
    cout << "5      " << fiveRoll << "      " <<""  << endl;
    cout << "6      " << sixRoll << "       " <<"" << endl;
```

I need it to print out the the one percent as a double. So I converted it as an int then to a double so it only prints two zeros like this (14.00) but its not converting at all its only printing 14

Comment: That's not the correct syntax for converting to a double?

Comment: Please include [mcve]. You can't really expect people to wade through a whole lot of code for a simple conversion problem.

Comment: If you want to print out doubles make your variables doubles.

Comment: When you convert to `int` you'll lose the fraction. Why do you need to show it as `.00` if they'll all be the same?

Comment: its what my teacher wants

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem, just as Barmar mentioned in his comment, is that although you want the value to be printed to 2 decimal points, you round off the number in `onePercent` when you do:

> ```
> onePercent = (int)((oneRoll*100.0) /numOfTimes); // Casting to "int" rounds off the number
> ```

Also, the declared data type for `onePercent` is `int` from the start:

> ```
> int onePercent, twoPercent, threePercent, fourPercent, fivePercent, sixPercent; // onePercent is an "int" here
> ```

So you don't need a typecast of `int`, because you're casting an `int` to an `int`.

Therefore, even if you print `onePercent`with 2 decimal-point precision, you will always get `.00` as a result.

I would recommend taking off the `(int)` cast from that expression itself, and changing the initial data type of `onePercent` to type `double`. If you do not want to change the data types for the other variables declared alongside `onePercent`, then declare `onePercent` as a `double` on another line. That way, the precision of the value after the calculation will be maintained, and you will be able to output it to 2 decimal places.

As an aside, to specify the number of decimal places to output, the `setprecision()` function can be used:

```
cout << setprecision(2) << ... << endl; // The value passed to "setprecision" is up to you.
```

Comment: @george129 If my answer worked, please select the checkmark next to my answer. I should turn green when you do so. Thanks!